# Low-level representation of an enum

Tags: c#

I have this enum:

```
enum Color
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
}
```

and the following IL generated code:

```
.class private auto ansi sealed WindowsFormsApplication1.Color
    extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
    // Fields
    .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
    .field public static literal valuetype WindowsFormsApplication1.Color RED = int32(0)
    .field public static literal valuetype WindowsFormsApplication1.Color GREEN = int32(1)
    .field public static literal valuetype WindowsFormsApplication1.Color BLUE = int32(2)

}
```

however my decompiler tool is not able to show me the C# decompiled code.

I'd like to know what really an enum is: is it a class type? is it a struct type?

What does it means `.class`? and `int32(0)`, ect.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: @barakcaf, but that link not answer my question.

Comment: *however my decompiler tool is not able to show me the C# decompiled code.* Change to a decent decompiler! Btw which one are you using?

Comment: ILSpy but also CodeReflect... they show me this the enum itself and not its decompiled code. Ex. private enum Color{
    // Fields
    RED = 0;
    GREEN = 1;
    BLUE = 2;
}

Comment: @xdevel2000 In ILSpy you can look at the IL code by selecting *IL* in the combo box. There is no intermediate step between C# and IL code. For small pieces of code you can use http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net , and select *IL* on the combo box in the right pane.

Comment: @xanatos, yes I know it. In fact I posted the IL code. I wanted to know if there were a C# decompiled code of that.

Comment: The `enum { RED, …` *is* the C# decompiled code. Decompilers recognise `.class private ... extends System.Enum` as an `enum`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual data type of an enum can be [a number of basic types, like `byte`, `int` and `long`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx). (In this case an `int`: `int32 value__`)

The `.class` defined contains a backing list of possible enum values (the `static` fields, and the enum value itself. (Note that `.class` is [also used for `struct` in CIL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118696/Hidden-Facts-of-C-Structures-in-terms-of-MSIL), so don't read that too literally) So I guess it is a struct, which makes more sense since it actually just contains one immutable backing field. It is treated like a basic type.

The `int32(0)` creates an integer with value `0`, the default value for the first item in the enum.